# Consume SOAP Web Service using certificates for security - Java

Tags: tomcat, ssl, soap, encryption, soap-client

I've been stuck trying to consume a web service which makes use of X.509 certificate token profile. I am making use of Tomcat server, also generated a self-signed certificate which I've passed on to the dudes at the server end. I've also imported their certificate into my keystore so far.
A few resources online advised on simply configuring tomcat to make use of SSL and then it would automatically take care of the signing and encryption of the soap request. I've done that without any success as the request I see from monitoring on my wireshark shows no changes to my plain soap request. 
I've also tried to implement the signature and encryption codewise, handled the signature aspect but got stuck on the encryption as XSS4J seems to no longer exist online anymore so I abandoned that route. 
I've also tried using SoapUI to send the plain request, imported the keys in the SoapUI and it was sent successfully. I got the signed and encrypted request using wireshark, and tried to play around with converting my plain request to become like the encrypted and signed message I saw from the successful SoapUI. Again I got stuck trying to generated the CipherValue of the  in the header section of the request.

1) Can anyone explain to me how to generate this cipherValue. What do I make use of? My key-pair, the server certificate or what. I have pasted the section containing the CipherValue below:

```
<xenc:EncryptedKey
                    Id="EK-D9EDC0ED19F6FBF32C1412176047017170"
                    xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <xenc:EncryptionMethod
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
                    <ds:KeyInfo
                        xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                            <wsse:Reference
                                URI="#D9EDC0ED19F6FBF32C1412176047017171"
                                ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                            </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        </ds:KeyInfo>
                    <xenc:CipherData>
                        <xenc:CipherValue>
                            Ab+xN46S1Q8A16YDXqHI/6ygQ78DS99OF9OMndldyTSLkBziUhFtvxJ504DbGJpvJAI1X5co7izH7xezFOL6x7/pl95TZajb3oSRhPX4Zj/oSCuID89292JSDxfaWJ2+CaR33h782YDTSlW8A8tnrx2DH9I14=
                            </xenc:CipherValue>
                        </xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:ReferenceList>
                        <xenc:DataReference
                            URI="#ED-108"/>
                        </xenc:ReferenceList>
                    </xenc:EncryptedKey>
```

2) Is there any cleaner way of allowing the certificate imported and my keystore handle the encryption, signature, and decryption of my request and responses from the server without my having to manually code this. Would appreciate any links with clear steps

Thanks

UPDATE: Server.xml for the tomcat I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8782" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxConnections="500" maxThreads="500" port="8709" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>

<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="150" port="8443" keystoreFile="c:\jcodes\certs\server.keystore" keystorePass="abcd1234" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>


<Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>
    <Context path="/resources" reloadable="true">
        <WatchedResource>/resources/css/jquery.dataTables.css</WatchedResource>
    </Context>
  </Host>
</Engine>
```

UPDATE: SOLVED
Finally solved this by using WSS4J. Got the sample request using SOAPUI and Wireshark, then proceeded to use WSS4J to sign and encrypt my SOAP requests.

Comment: When I tried this years ago it was certainly possible to configure Tomcat for it. In the end I did not decide for it as I could not validate the security of the Tomcat (or Glassfish) solution for it. And [fortunately](http://www.nds.rub.de/media/nds/veroeffentlichungen/2011/10/22/HowToBreakXMLenc.pdf) I created a solution of my own (blogging about the issue before the above paper was out). Unfortunately I cannot share the code - created for the company I work for. Tomcat was patched if I remember correctly. Can you show us your Tomcat config?

Comment: @owlstead
Thanks. Updated to show the tomcat config.

NB: I've just taken another route of trying to use WSS4J. Got to the point of importing my certificate exported from the public key of the keypair I generated. Importing into a JKS keystore works without any issues. Trying to do same for a PKCS12 keystore gives a KeyStoreException complaining that TrustedCertEntry is not supported. Even when I decide to convert a jks keystore containing the certificate to a PKCS12 type  of keystore, it yields same exception. Could you put me through the path how you went about solving the problem? Thanks

Comment: Aren't you mixing up application level security and SSL? I can see xenc in the XML and TLS in the configuration... That's security at different levels.

Comment: @owlstead Nope I am not. The xenc in the XML was part of the request I got viewing traffic using wireshark when I used SoapUI to send the XML request.
I pasted that XML to ask how the CipherValue was generated so I could generate a similar CipherValue